# For $x,y\geq0$ and $c_1>c_2>0$ with $ c_1x > c_2y$, can we say $-c_1x+c_2y\leq-c(x+y)$ for some $c>0$ that depends only on the $c_i$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $x,y \geq 0$ nonnegative real numbers and $c_1, c_2 > 0$ positive real constants with $c_1 > c_2$ and $ c_1x > c_2y.$ We assume that $c_1$ can be chosen arbitrarily larger than $c_2.$ Is it possible to do the following estimate:
$$ -c_1 x + c_2 y \leq - c \cdot (x+y),$$ with a positive real constant $c > 0$, which only depends on $c_1$ and $c_2$?

Comment: No such $c$. The inequality is written as $c \le \frac{c_1 + c_2}{1 + \frac{y}{x}} - c_2$. When $\frac{y}{x} \to \frac{c_1}{c_2}$, we have $\frac{c_1 + c_2}{1 + \frac{y}{x}} - c_2 \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $c_1=c$, and then $-c_1x+c_2y\leq -c_1(x+y)=-c_1x-c_1y\rightarrow c_2y\leq-c_1y$
But $y>0$ so $c_2\leq-c_1$, which is wrong.$\square$